# compile OpenAES for 64bit architecture for both windows and mac

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, cryptography, aes

I want to compile the OpenAES library so that I can use it in my project.
According to the `README` file, it has descriptions of how to compile for Windows and MacOS but it doesn't have any mention of how to build it for 64-bit architectures.

Is it possible to compile this library for 64-bit archs or does it not have support for such?

Comment: Attempted to improve the language a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I completed the process to create a oaes_lib.lib

Steps:
1. Download: OpenAES-master.zip,  from  http://code.google.com/p/openaes 
2. Install CMake.
3. Unzip OpenAES-master.zip at C:\Devs\OpenAES (at my case)
4. Create a library folder: C:\Devs\OpenAES\libs
5. With CMake gui tool opened. Choose: "Where is the source code:" "C:\Devs\OpenAES"   and "Where to build the binaries": "C:\Devs\OpenAES\libs"
6. It will ask you for your compiler. 
7. Then look for the oaes.sln file and open it with visual studio
8. Build the projects, after all, look at C:\Devs\OpenAES\libs\Debug\oaes_lib.lib file.

I'm not sure if the .lib file works, I am on it.

Answer (score 0):

I found another library por AES:  QPolarSSL  https://github.com/azadkuh/qpolarssl

which is based on mbedtls. Very easy to implement.